# Does compiler optimization affect on dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c, memory-management

I know sometimes compilers remove unused arrays.

But my question is do the affect on dynamic variables which are allocated using malloc or just the stack variables ?

Is malloc a compile time operation or runtime?

If it is runtime can compiler remove an array which is allocated using malloc or it can only remove the arrays which are fixed size ?

Comment: if you write `if (0) malloc(10);` the compiler optimization will impact the dynamic memory allocation removing it :-)

Comment: The exact code and compiler/settings are needed to answer the question. There are already multiple examples provided of how the malloc (and even pointer variable, etc.) COULD be eliminated, if appearing in a place where such optimizations are possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to remove `malloc` and its family because memory allocation is not an observable behavior.

For example, both `gcc` and `clang` [optimize these functions](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ccstdlib%3E%0A%0Aint+foo()%7B%0A++++malloc(10)%3B%0A++++return+42%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+bar()%7B%0A++++int*+p+%3D+(int*)malloc(10)%3B%0A++++*p+%3D+17%3B%0A++++return+42%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+qax()%7B%0A++++int*+p+%3D+(int*)malloc(10)%3B%0A++++*p+%3D+17%3B%0A++++int+a+%3D+*p+%2B+25%3B%0A++++free(p)%3B%0A++++return+a%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.0245109928975,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic+-Werror',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),k:49.97548900710252,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to just `return 42` with `-O2`:

```
int foo(){
    malloc(10);
    return 42;
}

int bar(){
    int* p = (int*)malloc(10);
    *p = 17;
    return 42;
}

int qax(){
    int* p = (int*)malloc(10);
    *p = 17;
    int a = *p + 25;
    free(p);
    return a;
}
```

Even a more complex one is [successfully optimized](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ccstdlib%3E%0A%0Avoid+bar(int*+xs)%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+10%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++xs%5Bi%5D+%3D+i+%2B+35%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+foo()%7B%0A++++int*+xs+%3D+(int*)malloc(40)%3B%0A++++bar(xs)%3B%0A++++return+xs%5B7%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.0245109928975,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic+-Werror',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),k:49.97548900710252,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to `return 42` by clang:

```
void bar(int* xs){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        xs[i] = i + 35;
    }
}

int foo(){
    int* xs = (int*)malloc(40);
    bar(xs);
    return xs[7];
}
```

But you should not expect much: such optimizations are unusual and, in general, unreliable.

Comment: My concern is not "to optimization". It is "not to optimization". I have a big array which is allocated dynamicly using malloc but it is unused. The question asks me whether this array be deleted or not by compiler.

Comment: What is the storage lifetime of the variable of the malloc? Compilers can only generally optimize locally as, globally, “something else” might need the object if it could be accessed.. if the array is guaranteed unused by code inspection, just remove it, which will also avoid other developer confusion.

Comment: @user2864740: The lifetime of the object is not related to the issue you are raising regarding “something else” accessing the object. Arrays allocated via `malloc` have *allocated* storage duration (that is a named storage duration in the C standard, like static, thread, and automatic). But, regardless of the storage duration, if the compiler can see how the storage is or is not accessed, it is free to optimize that (by, if there are accesses, changing them to equivalent code or, if there are no accesses, by removing the allocation and the free).

Comment: @user2864740: As an example, if a routine uses `malloc` to get some space, passes the space to another routine, and then passes the space to `free`, it is allowed to replace the `malloc` and `free` with space allocated on the stack since, whatever the other routine does with the space, it can no longer use it after the `free` is executed, so it does not matter that it might have kept a pointer to it (the pointer becomes invalid when the `free` is executed), so stack space is just as good as allocated space in regard to observable behavior.

Comment: @Ramtin Mousavi I'm not sure I entirely understand it, but in general you can't be sure. Even something innocent, like storing a reference to the array in another variable, may prevent it from being deleted. Oh and in debug builds the compiler acts as dumb as possible, so it's almost certain the array will stay in those.

Answer (score 0):

---

As you have changed the question:

variables with the external linkage will not be optimized out. Other potentially yes. They are not "removed" - they are optimised out - ie they do not exist in the compiled code

[image]

I think it is self explanatory.

Comment: There are developer tools with cross-module optimization, and, even if they or the versions of tools you are using now do not optimize in this situation, they might in the future. You should not make general statements about behaviors without either specifying that they apply only to prescribed circumstances (such as certain compilers of today) or basing them on applicable rules (such as the C standard). As far as the C standard is concerned, whether something is external or not is irrelevant—optimization is permitted if the translator ensures the same observable behavior results.